# Find and Replace, replace one pattern with another

Tags: text-editors, find-and-replace

I am working Sql Sever Management studio. 
In my query window, I want to replace a pattern as follows:-

Find:-              ''myText''

Replace With:-  'myText'

The gist is that myText can be any string text so I want to replace all strings 
enclosed in two single quotes on both sides ''myString'' to string with only one 
single quote on both side 'myString'

Answer (score 0):

SSMS has option for wildcard match (and also regex match if you need to match more complex patterns):
You'd need to check `use` and then `wildcards` from the list, see below:

[image]